# change the data format from individual rows to single row

Tags: excel

I have excel data with Name in one column, and the Product in next column. I want to change it to a new format in which the products will appear in adjacent cells for the same name, instead of in additional rows. Eg. From:

```
Name1  Product1
Name1  Product2
Name2  Product1
Name3  Pr0duct4
Name3  Product6
Name3  Product1
```

To:

```
Name1 Product1 Product2
Name2 Product1
Name3 Product1 Product4 Product6
```

How can this be done?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Please
[edit] your question to show the code you have written so
far and where you are stuck, then we can try to help with
specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions:

1. Names are in Column A, start in Row 1 (no header)
2. Products are in Column B, start in Row 1 (no header)
3. Right of the data you do not have other data, as the code deletes the whole row.

Press Alt+F11, Insert New Module, paste the code below, change it according to your sheet (e.g. in which row does the data start etc.) and run it. (Note: make sure that your sheet with this data is the active Sheet, i.e. that you click on it before you run the code.)

```
    Sub reformat()

    Dim firstrow, lastrow, count As Integer
    Dim emptyCell As Range


        firstrow = 1
        count = 0

        With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

            lastrow = .Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row

            For i = firstrow + 1 To lastrow

                If .Range("A" & i) = .Range("A" & i - 1) Then

                    Set emptyCell = .Range("A" & i - 1)
                    Do
                    Set emptyCell = emptyCell.Offset(, 1)
                    Loop While Not IsEmpty(emptyCell.Value)

                    emptyCell.Value = .Range("B" & i).Value

                    .Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete

                    i = i - 1
                    count = count + 1

                    If count + i >= lastrow Then Exit Sub

                End If

            Next i

        End With

    End Sub
```

Let me know if this helps or you have any other questions.

Edit: if you do not have a lot of data, and it is sorted by Name, it might be faster to just do it manually with: Copy -> PasteSpecial (Transpose)

Comment: Thanks, It is working. I wrote a similar code.

Comment: Cool, please accept it as the answer then. :)