# change the data format from individual rows over many columns to multiple rows over one column with a data id column

Tags: sql, postgresql, unpivot

I have csv data with ID (name) and 100-200 columns with data values for each ID (name).

Eg. I want to convert from:

```
Name1 Value1 Value2 Comment1 Location7

Name2 Value3 Value4 Comment2

Name3 Value5 Comment3 Comment4 Location8
```

To:

```
Name1  Value1

Name1  Value2

Name1  Comment1

Name1  Location7

Name2  Value3

Name2  Value4

Name2  Comment2

Name3  Value5 

Name3  Comment3 

Name3  Comment4 

Name3  Location8
```

I basically need to do the opposite of this:

[change the data format from individual rows to single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37004456/change-the-data-format-from-individual-rows-to-single-row)

It can be in excel preferably, or SQL which I am trying to learn.

Thanks for any input, unfortunately the software I am using requires this.

Comment: Hi, welcome.  You'll have much better luck if you narrow your question and provide examples of your work.  What have you tried?  What is result you're seeing?   People typically don't want to do other's work for them.  
Check out this page for advice to maximize your chances: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lateral join.  It is a little unclear exactly what your data looks like, but something like this:

```
select t.name, v.value
from t cross join lateral
     (values (t.value1), (t.value2), (t.comment1), . . . 
     ) v(value)
where v.value is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple with Power Query (available in Excel 2010+), and all doable from the UI

- Select the first (Name) column
- `Unpivot` other columns
- Delete the attribute column

**MCode** *(although you don't really need it)*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}, {"Column4", type text}, {"Column5", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Column1"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]